# Convert Java tokenizing regex into Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, infix-notation

As an answer to my question [Tokenizing an infix string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408570/tokenizing-an-infix-string-in-java), I got the regex `(?<=[^\.a-zA-Z\d])|(?=[^\.a-zA-Z\d]`. However, now I'm writing the same code in Javascript, and I'm stuck as to how I would get a Javascript regex to do the same thing.

For example, if I have the string `sin(4+3)*2`, I would need it parsed into `["sin","(","4","+","3",")","*","2"]`

What regex would I use to tokenize the string into each individual part.

Before, what I did is I just did a string replace of every possible token, and put a space around it, then split on that whitespace. However, that code quickly became very bloated.

The operators I would need to split on would be the standard math operators (`+,-,*,/,^)`, as well as function names `(sin,cos,tan,abs,etc...)`, and commas

What is a fast, efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of regular expression grouping to do this. You need a regex that combines the different possible tokens, and you apply it repeatedly.

I like to separate out the different parts; it makes it easier to maintain and extend:

```
var tokens = [
  "sin",
  "cos",
  "tan",
  "\\(",
  "\\)",
  "\\+",
  "-",
  "\\*",
  "/",
  "\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?"
];
```

You glue those all together into a big regular expression with `|` between each token:

```
var rtok = new RegExp( "\\s*(?:(" + tokens.join(")|(") + "))\\s*", "g" );
```

You can then tokenize using regex operations on your source string:

```
function tokenize( expression ) {
  var toks = [], p;

  rtok.lastIndex = p = 0; // reset the regex
  while (rtok.lastIndex < expression.length) {
    var match = rtok.exec(expression);

    // Make sure we found a token, and that we found
    // one without skipping garbage

    if (!match || rtok.lastIndex - match[0].length !== p)
      throw "Oops - syntax error";

    // Figure out which token we matched by finding the non-null group
    for (var i = 1; i < match.length; ++i) {
      if (match[i]) {
        toks.push({
          type: i,
          txt: match[i]
        });
        // remember the new position in the string
        p = rtok.lastIndex;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return toks;
}
```

That just repeatedly matches the token regex against the string. The regular expression was created with the "g" flag, so the regex machinery will automatically keep track of where to start matching after each match we make. When it doesn't see a match, or when it does but has to skip invalid stuff to find it, we know there's a syntax error.  When it does match, it records in the token array which token it matched (the index of the non-null group) and the matched text. By remembering the matched token index, it saves you the trouble of having to figure out what each token string *means* after you've tokenized; you just have to do a simple numeric comparison.

Thus calling `tokenize( "sin(4+3) * cos(25 / 3)" )` returns:

```
[ { type: 1, txt: 'sin' },
  { type: 4, txt: '(' },
  { type: 10, txt: '4' },
  { type: 6, txt: '+' },
  { type: 10, txt: '3' },
  { type: 5, txt: ')' },
  { type: 8, txt: '*' },
  { type: 2, txt: 'cos' },
  { type: 4, txt: '(' },
  { type: 10, txt: '25' },
  { type: 9, txt: '/' },
  { type: 10, txt: '3' },
  { type: 5, txt: ')' } ]
```

Token type 1 is the `sin` function, type 4 is left paren, type 10 is a number, etc.

*edit* — if you want to match identifiers like "x" and "y", then I'd probably use a different set of token patterns, with one just to match any identifiers. That'd mean that the parser would not find out directly about "sin" and "cos" etc. from the lexer, but that's OK.  Here's an alternative list of token patterns:

```
var tokens = [
  "[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]*",
  "\\(",
  "\\)",
  "\\+",
  "-",
  "\\*",
  "/",
  "\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?"
];
```

Now any identifier will be a type 1 token.

Comment: Sorry, but when I run this at http://jsfiddle.net/P5vmY/, it just keeps throwing a syntax error. Did I implement it wrong?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 well I didn't include anything to match "x". It'd have to be a slightly different set of token patterns; instead of looking explicitly for "sin" etc. you'd just look for identifiers, and the qualify those separately in the parser.

Comment: Thanks. I used a slight modification of this, where I added an attribute that specified if something was a number, variable, operator, parenthesis, etc

Comment: @scrblnrd3 yup, great idea!  Always make code that knows stuff convey the stuff to other code!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will do *everything* of what you want to achieve, but it works for me:

```
'sin(4+3)*2'.match(/\d+\.?\d*|[a-zA-Z]+|\S/g);

// ["sin", "(", "4", "+", "3", ")", "*", "2"]
```

You may replace `[a-zA-Z]+` part with `sin|cos|tan|etc` to support only math functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just offer up a few possibilities:

```
[a-zA-Z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?|.
```